# SpringMVC require login to view a page using sessions

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I've build a simple SpringMVC login system that works fine, but I want to restrict pages to say only uses with a valid login can see them.  If I was using just JSP I would check the...

```
if ( login.equals("admin") && password.equals("guess") ) {
        // Valid login
        session.setAttribute("authorized", "yes");
} else {
        // Invalid login
        session.setAttribute("authorized", "no");
}
```

But how do I globally set in my application in SpringMVC if a set of servlets can be accessed by a session?  I can set the session that's fine, but in SpringMVC should my session handling be done at the controller or the servlet-context.xml (or even web.xml) so I can check just say "if user is logged in show this page, otherwise homepage".

My login.jsp is a very simple...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello please login to this application  
</h1>
<script>

        function login(){
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $.post('login', { username : username , password : password }, function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
            } );
        }

</script>
Username : <input id="username" type="text" />
Password : <input id="password" type="password" />
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Click me" onclick="login()" />
<form name="next" action="auth/details" method="get">
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Go Through"/>
</form>
<div id="results" />
</body>
</html>
```

I only want controller at auth/details to return the the details there if the user has logged in, what's the best approach to this?  Cookies/session etc?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like reinventing the wheel. [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) already handles your case and with few lines of XML in `web.xml` (defining a servlet filter) and some basic configuration it will restrict access to selected URLs, provide login/logout screens, handle users storage and HTTP session management.

Although known to be very complicated, the default configuration (`auto`) is enough to start:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

See the [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html). Also [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html) seems to get a lot of traction nowadays.

If, for some reason, you don't want to introduce Spring Security to your stack, Spring MVC [interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) are a good place to implement cross-cutting security logic. You have access to original request and response, so you can discover URLs and check the HTTP session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using spring security for this I suggest you look it up and use it. It's so much easier to do things like this using spring security:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal

Use: intercept-url

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Spring Security JSP Taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html). Once configured, it allows you to do things like

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('user')">
    Only logged in users will see this.
</sec:authorize>
```